# Array bounds with 0-sized array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, bounds, allocatable-array

When allocating zero-sized arrays in Fortran, I am getting counterintuitive behavior.

This code:

```
program test_zerosized
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable :: a(:),b(:)
  allocate(a(0))
  print *, ' a lower bound = ',lbound(a,1)
  print *, ' a upper bound = ',ubound(a,1)

  allocate(b(0:0))
  print *, ' b lower bound = ',lbound(b,1)
  print *, ' b upper bound = ',ubound(b,1)
  return
end program test_zerosized
```

Produces the following output:

```
  a lower bound =            1
  a upper bound =            0
  b lower bound =            0
  b upper bound =            0
```

Is my compiler (gcc/gfortran 6.2.0) standard conforming? I don't get why `lbound(a,1)==1` instead of `lbound(a,1)==0`, since the total total array size is of zero elements. Thanks!

Comment: Well if Lbound( a ) = 0 and Ubound( a ) = 0 it's not zero sized, there's 1 element, namely a( 0 )

Answer (score 4):

The result you observe is the correct behaviour.

The array `a` is zero-sized, and `lbound` works on such arrays (F2008, 13.7.90) (my emphasis):

> If ARRAY is a whole array and either ARRAY is an assumed-size array of rank DIM or **dimension DIM of ARRAY has nonzero extent**, LBOUND (ARRAY, DIM) has a value equal to the lower bound for subscript DIM of ARRAY. **Otherwise the result value is 1.**

`ubound` works in a complementary way.

Compare this with the size-1 array `b` with lower bound zero and upper bound zero.

The allocatable nature of `a` is not relevant, and you would see the same result with an explicit shape array of zero size.

Comment: got it, thanks @francescalus, so in some sense the standard wants bound-based size checking to be consistent: for array a, `size(a) == ubound(a)-lbound(a)+1 == 0-1+1 == 0`, while for array b, `size(b) == ubound(b)-lbound(b)+1 == 0-0+1 == 1`, which contains 1 element as @Ian Bush pointed out

Comment: Indeed (taking care to consider the extents/bounds/sizes in terms of individual ranks).